CMAKE failed to create static library using In windows Intel compiler since always use icx instead lib.exe
When I use CMAKE to create a library like
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=icx.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=icx.exe

it always tries to link using icx instead of lib.
C:\PROGRA~2\INTELS~1\COMPIL~1.166\windows\bin\icx.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\getopt_static.dir\objects1.rsp @<< -fuse-ld=llvm-lib -o E:\intel\MYSTRAN-15.2.1\wingetopt\lib\getopt_static.lib /Qoption,link,/machine:x64 

It emits the error:
icx: command line warning #10159: invalid argument for option '/fuse-ld' [/Winvalid-command-line-argument]
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\INTELS~1\COMPIL~1.166\windows\bin\icx.exe' : return code '0x619'

it completely different if I use MSVC:
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" .. 

C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3\2019\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1423~1.281\bin\Hostx64\x64\lib.exe /nologo /machine:x64 /out:E:\intel\MYSTRAN-15.2.1\superlu\wingetopt\lib\getopt_static.lib @CMakeFiles\getopt_static.dir\objects1.rsp 

How to tell CMake to behave like MSVC creating static library using lib instead icx?
